# multiple setinterval issue with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am performing setInterval for following code.
On a button click i have to perform below ones one by one

```
// show VM started

    vmstart = setInterval(function () {
      $.get('/getVMstatus', function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
          clearInterval(vmstart);
          $("#vmstart").show();
          $("#vmstart").html(data[0].ip)+".....</br>";
          $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
        }
      });
    }, 5000);


// get VM IP Address
    inter = setInterval(function () {
      $.get('/getVm', function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
          clearInterval(inter);
          $("#vmipdiv").show();
          $("#vmipdiv").html("VM IP : " + data[0].ip);
          $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
        }
      });
    }, 6000);

// Test start
teststart = setInterval(function () {
      $.get('/geteststatus', function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
          clearInterval(teststart);
          $("#teststart").show();
          $("#teststart").html("Test Starting in "+data[0].ip+"</br>");
          $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
        }
      });
    }, 11000);
```

what i need in the button click is

first call `/getVMstatus` only after filling data to html call `/getVM` after getting this data call `/getteststatus` how it is possible?

Comment: You would be better off using [Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) instead of direct calls to `setInterval()` in this situation.

Comment: please delete this question.i tried but no way

Comment: i asked the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402433/multiple-set-interval-conflict-in-jquery plese reply this question.I would like to delete this one

Comment: You can't, it has upvoted answers. Why would you want to delete it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can call one function inside another

```
$.get('/getVMstatus', function (data) {
    if (data != "") {
        $("#vmstart").show();
        $("#vmstart").html(data[0].ip)+".....</br>";
        $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {
            $.get('/getVm', function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    $("#vmipdiv").show();
                    $("#vmipdiv").html("VM IP : " + data[0].ip);
                    $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {
                        $.get('/geteststatus', function (data) {
                            if (data != "") {
                                $("#teststart").show();
                                $("#teststart").html("Test Starting in "+data[0].ip+"</br>");
                                $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try done callback

```
    / show VM started
          $.get('/getVMstatus', function (data) {
            if (data != "") {

              $("#vmstart").show();
              $("#vmstart").html(data[0].ip)+".....</br>";
              $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
            }
          }).done(function(){$.get('/getVm', function (data) {
            if (data != "") {

              $("#vmipdiv").show();
              $("#vmipdiv").html("VM IP : " + data[0].ip);
              $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
            }
          }).done(function(){
$.get('/geteststatus', function (data) {
            if (data != "") {

              $("#teststart").show();
              $("#teststart").html("Test Starting in "+data[0].ip+"</br>");
              $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
            }
          });
});
});
```

Comment: but i have to set interval also in each function

Comment: while calling `\getVmStatus` db doent contain any data.db will contain data only after few seconds.same thing is hapepning in case of`getVm` and `getteststatus`

Comment: @sush in that code no need of interval it executes by a order

Comment: if db contains any data i will clear the interval also.it is alos mentioned in my code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402433/multiple-set-interval-conflict-in-jquery