# multiple set interval conflict in jquery

Tags: jquery

In the following code i set time interval, but get out of time when working together. What am I doing wrong? Any improvement on the code would be appreciated too...

```
// show VM started

    vmstart = setInterval(function () {
      $.get('/getVMstatus', function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
          clearInterval(vmstart);
          $("#vmstart").show();
          $("#vmstart").html(data[0].ip)+".....</br>";
          $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
        }
      });
    }, 5000);


// get VM IP Address
    inter = setInterval(function () {
      $.get('/getVm', function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
          clearInterval(inter);
          $("#vmipdiv").show();
          $("#vmipdiv").html("VM IP : " + data[0].ip);
          $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
        }
      });
    }, 6000);

// Test start
teststart = setInterval(function () {
      $.get('/geteststatus', function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
          clearInterval(teststart);
          $("#teststart").show();
          $("#teststart").html("Test Starting in "+data[0].ip+"</br>");
          $.post('/deleteReport', function (data) {});
        }
      });
    }, 15000);
```

Comment: please dont close this question..please..

Comment: Same `question` same `OP` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401540/multiple-setinterval-issue-with-jquery

Comment: before closing my question..please give me an idea for solving this plm

Answer (score 0):

You can a use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) with `dataType:json` to get all `ip` like,

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/get_all_report', 
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data != "") {
        clearInterval(teststart);
        $("#teststart, #vmipdiv, #vmstart").show();
        $("#vmstart").html(data.vmstart)+".....</br>"; // data.vmstart ip of vmstart
        $("#vmipdiv").html("VM IP : " + data.vmipdiv); // data.vmipdiv ip of vmipdiv
        $("#teststart").html("Test Starting in "+data.teststart+"</br>"); // data.teststart ip of teststart
        $.post('/delete_all_report', function (data) {});
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: You have to make a `common url` like `get_all_report` and combine all 3 urls into this one and return `json data` having all `IP's`. I just give an `idea` not `full code` you have to try, now.